# JavaScript does not work on pages other than my MasterPage and pages that aren't linked to it

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web, master-pages

Sorry for the bad english :P

I'm using ASP.NET

I'm trying to use a JavaScript that I've found on the Internet to set masks to my telephone and cellphone text fields, but the JS code just work at the fields that are located at my MasterPage. I don't have much experience with JS (almost none) and I have no idea how to resolve this since there is no error at my Logcat.

I tried to reference it at my MasterPage's head, body and inside the ContentPlaceHolder.

Here is the JS code:

```
function mascara(o, f) {
        v_obj = o
        v_fun = f
        setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
    }
function execmascara() {
v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
}
function mtel(v) {
v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");             
v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g, "($1)$2"); 
v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/, "$1-$2");   
return v;
}
function id(el) {
return document.getElementById(el);
}
window.onload = function () {

id('txtTelefone').onkeypress = function () { //Located at MasterPage - working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
id('txtCelular').onkeypress = function () { //Located at MasterPage - working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
id('telefoneContato').onkeypress = function () { //Located at Contact Page - not working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
id('txtCelularUser').onkeypress = function () { //Located at User Page - not working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
id('txtTelefoneUser').onkeypress = function () { //Located at User Page - not working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
}
```

As I said before I tried to reference my JS file in some places, the codes that I tried were:

```
<script  src="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("../Componentes/js/mascaras.js") %>"></script>

<script src="../Componentes/js/mascaras.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the fields are located in diferent pages, I also tried to put the code directly at the pages but I had no luck.

I think that I don't need to post my entire MasterPage here, then I'll put just the head, but if exists a need I will edit the post.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagens/icone.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />


<link href="../Componentes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="../Componentes/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="../Componentes/css/MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Fontes/Fontes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Componentes/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Componentes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<%--Mask Scripts--%>
<script  src="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("../Componentes/js/mascaras.js") %>"></script> 
<script src="../Componentes/js/mascaras.js"></script>


<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

**EDIT 1**

Tried this:

```
id('<%= txtTelefoneContato.ClientID %>').onkeypress = function () { //Located at Contact Page - Still not working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
id('<%= txtCelularUser.ClientID %>').onkeypress = function () { //Located at User Page - Still not working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
id('<%= txtTelefoneUser.ClientID %>').onkeypress = function () { //Located at User Page- Still not working
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
```

The reference to the script is at MasterPage head. But the problem still the same

**EDIT2**

Im receiving this when I inspect my page:

[Error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9ExB.png)

[Error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdkaD.png)

**Resolved**

As *VDWWD* explained, I just put the JS code directly at the .aspx pages with this modification:

from:,

```
id('txtCelularUser').onkeypress = function () { 
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
```

to:

```
id('<%= txtCelularUser.ClientID %>').onkeypress = function () { 
    mascara(this, mtel);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: check your browser's console window for contact page. is there any error or not?

Comment: Yes, there is. 
`mascaras.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeypress' of null `
 --- and this ---
`mascaras.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeypress' of null`

Comment: you can try with $(document).ready(function(){}) insted of window.load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like this when accessing elements with JavaScript that have master pages. And it's also better to use it even without master pages. If you should change the ID in you don't have to change it also in your script.

```
id('<%= txtTelefoneUser.ClientID %>').onkeypress
```

If you look at the HTML source you will see that the ID of the element has been changed from `txtTelefoneUser` to something like this `ContentPlaceHolder_txtTelefoneUser`. Aspnet adds a prefix to ensure every element has a unique ID.
You will see the same usage of prefix in elements that repeat data like GridView/Repeater/DataList etc.

**UPDATE**

If you put the javascript in an external file you can put a reference to it on the master page like this (assuming `Componentes` is a folder in the root):

```
<script src="/Componentes/js/mascaras.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However putting `<%= txtTelefoneUser.ClientID %>` in an external file will not work, only on an .aspx page. To make that work declare those elements as variables an assign them on the aspx page while using them in the external js file.

Below a demo:

In the external javascript file:

```
var myElement;
function myFunction() {
    myElement.value = "Success!";
}
```

and then on the .aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myElement = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
</script>
```

Comment: Were I should reference my script?
Because I've done what you said but the problem reamains the same.
And thanks for the attention.

Comment: Then, can I use the first example if I put the code directly on the .aspx page?

Comment: Yes that's right. If you write the javascript inline then it should work.

Comment: PS `ContentPlaceHolder` should be outside the `<head>` but inside the `<body>` tag.

Comment: I'm new here so one more thing, how do I chose this as the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I found that the elements that area inside the Content to be found in javascript must have the name of the content ID in front more undeline and the name of the element ID, you are looking for.

example:

```
document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_img1").setAttribute("src", 123);
```